# extract a part of string using regex

Tags: regex, perl

I have a text file with pattern as below.

> "s|o|m|j|n|k|v|a|l|u|e|s|cap1{capture|these|values}|s|o|m|j|n|k|v|a|l|u|e|s|cap2[capture|these|values]|s|o|m|j|n|k|v|a|l|u|e|s|CAP3{[capture|these|values]|[capture|these|values]}"

I am trying to extract the values *cap1*, *cap2*, *CAP3*.

I am trying with regex `"([a-z]|[|])cap1(\{(.*?)\})([a-z]|[|]|[0-9])"` but with no luck any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you describe what exactly your problem is? The regex seems fine to me.

Comment: @user4911736, Please check my answer if I misunderstood some thing please take a note, then I will improve it. but if it's correct I will add more explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand you want to extract the value of cap1, cap2, CAP3 one by one. There are 3 regex then

**For** `cap1`

```
cap1\{([^\}]*)\}
```

**Explanation**

`cap1\{` match text `cap1{`,

`([^\}]*)` capture any characters except `}` to group `$1`,

`\}` match text `}`.

**For** `cap2`

```
cap2\[([^\]]*)\]
```

**Explanation**

`cap2\[` match text `cap2[`,

`([^\]]*)` capture any characters except `]` to group `$1`,

`\]` match text `]`.

**For** `CAP3`

```
CAP3\{\[([^\]]*)\]\|\[([^\]]*)\]\}
```

**Explanation**

`CAP3\{` match text `CAP3{`,

`\[([^\]]*)\]\|\[([^\]]*)\]` capture any characters except `]` to groups `$1`, `$2` respectively,

`\}` match text `}`.

**Additional:** Thank you for a comment from @Borodin, to do this task you don't need to use lookaround but in case that you want to do search and replace, the lookaround may be necessary.

**For** `cap1`: `(?<=cap1\{)([^\}]*)(?=\})`

**For** `cap2`: `(?<=cap2\[)([^\]]*)(?=\])`

**For** `CAP3`: `(?<=CAP3\{)\[([^\]]*)\]\|\[([^\]]*)\](?=\})`

Comment: There is no need for fancy look-around constructs. You're capturing the substring that you want, so `cap1\{([^}]*)\}` etc. is fine

Comment: @Borodin Thank you, yes it doesn't need.

Comment: @terces907: You should also escape all curly brackets that are meant to match literally. Otherwise you will get a warning `Unescaped brace in regex is deprecated` unless you have `no warnings 'deprecated'` in place

Answer (score 0):

Using a pattern such as this should work:

```
[{\[]+([^}{\]\[]+)[\]}]+
```

**Code**:

```
$searchText =~ m/[{\[]+([^}{\]\[]+)[\]}]+/
```

**Example**:

https://regex101.com/r/qI3fI6/1

Answer (score 0):

#### Update

I apologise -- I initially mistook your question for something more trivial

Essentially you want to perform a `split` on pipe `|` characters, excluding those found inside pairs of brackets or braces `[ ... ]` or `{ ... }`. As long as you don't need to take account of nesting inside brackets of the same type (i.e. braces will only ever contain brackets, and brackets will only ever contain braces) then it is simply done like this

```
my @matches = $s =~ m{ \w+ ( \{ [^{}]* \} | \[ [^\[\]]* \] ) }gx;
print "$_\n" for @matches;
```

#### output

```
{capture|these|values}
[capture|these|values]
{[capture|these|values]|[capture|these|values]}
```

The data you show has no instances of braces containing braces, or brackets containing brackets, but I suspect that there is no theoretical limit to the nesting of the your data in which case some recursion is necessary

The regex pattern in the program below defines the text that can appear *inside* a pair of matching brackets as a pipe-delimited sequence of

- another pair of matching brackets and their content `[ ... ]`
- another pair of matching braces and their content `{ ... }`
- a sequence of *word* characters like `capture` and `values`

A pattern matching that is inside the *second* pair of capturing parentheses. It is a recursive pattern that calls itself using relative numbering `(?-1)`. That could also be absolute numbering `(?2)` but it would have to be changed if the number of preceding captures was changed

The complete pattern looks for and captures a series of word characters immediately before the recursive pattern to account for the `cap1`, `cap2` etc. This allows the result of a glolbal search to be assigned directly to a hash with the result show below

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $s = "s|o|m|j|n|k|v|a|l|u|e|s|cap1{capture|these|values}|s|o|m|j|n|k|v|a|l|u|e|s|cap2[capture|these|values]|s|o|m|j|n|k|v|a|l|u|e|s|CAP3{[capture|these|values]|[capture|these|values]}";

my %captures = $s =~ m{
    ( (?> \w+ ) )
    (
        \{ (?-1) (?> \| (?-1) )* \} |
        \[ (?-1) (?> \| (?-1) )* \] |
        \w+
    )
}gx;

use Data::Dump;
dd \%captures;
```

#### output

```
{
  cap1 => "{capture|these|values}",
  cap2 => "[capture|these|values]",
  CAP3 => "{[capture|these|values]|[capture|these|values]}",
}
```

---

#### Original answer

It looks like you want all identifiers that are preceded by a pipe `|` character and followed by either a square or curly opening bracket `[` or `{`

This program will do that for you

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10;

my $s = "s|o|m|j|n|k|v|a|l|u|e|s|cap1{capture|these|values}|s|o|m|j|n|k|v|a|l|u|e|s|cap2[capture|these|values]|s|o|m|j|n|k|v|a|l|u|e|s|CAP3{[capture|these|values]|[capture|these|values]}";

for ( $s ) {
    my @captures = /\|(\w+)[\[\{]/g;
    say for @captures;
}
```

#### output

```
cap1
cap2
CAP3
```